# Use Twitterboostrap 4 mixins in custom namespace

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am compiling twitter boostrap 4 with sass in my custom namespace:

```
//./main.scss
.twitter-bootstrap {
    @import "./my-scss/bootstrap-overrides";
}
@import ./my-scss/custom.scss
```

In `bootstrap-overrides.scss` I only import some components (variables, mixins, functions are imported in `bootstrap-overrides.scss`

In a custom scss I want to use a mixin:

```
//./my-scss/custom.scss
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
...
}
```

My compiler show an error:

```
Error: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
18 │ ┌   @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
19 │ │     ...
20 │ │     
21 │ └   }
   ╵
  main.scss 15:9                  root stylesheet
```

How can I use twitterbootstrap 4 mixins in scss files?

Answer (score 1):

Import in this order

```
@import "path/scss/functions";
@import "path/scss/variables";
@import "path/scss/mixins";
@import ./my-scss/custom.scss;
```

Now you can use all bootstrap mixins in `custom.scss`.

Comment: I use a namespace for Twitter bootstrap, with your solution I miss the namespace

Comment: for the namespace, you need to wrap your bootstrap scss in your wrapper, like .twitter-bootstrap {
 @import "path/scss/bootstrap";
}